# Двумерный массив  Perl записать как свойство класса

Tags: perl

Здравсвуйте!
Подскажите, как записать в свойство класса двумерный массив, чтобы можно было потом обращаться к элементам этого массива через этот класс?
Есть такой конструктор

```
sub new {
my ($class_name, @arr_elem) =  @_;
print $arr_elem[0];
my $self = {};
$self->{elem} = @arr_elem;
bless $self, matrix;
return $self;
}
sub minimum {
my($self) = @_;
my $min = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i<$self->{str}; $i++)
{
for($j = 0; $j<$self->{col};$j++)
{
    if ($self->{elem}[$i][$j]<=$min)
    {
        $min = $self->{elem}[$i][$j];
    }
}
}
return $min;
}
```

Или вызов в конструкторе не так

```
 $new_matrix  = matrix->new (matrix, @elem_matrix, "A");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Есть такой конструктор

И он работает?

> как записать в свойство класса двумерный массив

Точно так же, как и и любой другой массив: либо по ссылке (хорошо, но может потребовать создания копии внутри конструктора, если оригинальный массив может меняться), либо по значению (плохо). Пример первого варианта, без копирования:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @matrix = ( [1, 2], [3, 4] );
my $myobj = new myClass( \@matrix );

for my $i ( 0..$#{$myobj->{matrix}} )
{
    for my $j ( 0..$#{$myobj->{matrix}->[$i]} )
    {
        printf( "[%2d,%-2d] %d\n", $i, $j, $myobj->{matrix}->[$i]->[$j] );
    }
}

package myClass;
sub new
{
    my ( $class, $matrix ) = @_;
    my $self =
    {
        matrix  => $matrix
    };
    bless( $self,$class );
    $self;
}
1;
```

> Или вызов в конструкторе не так
>
> `$new_matrix  = matrix->new (matrix, @elem_matrix, "A");`

До этого момента вы говорили на русском, может быть не очень правильном, но всё-таки на русском, который можно понять. А тут бэмс - и перешли на наречие племени мумбо-юмбо, известное только вам и им...

Одно могу сказать: такой вызов конструктора возможен в принципе, но добраться до параметра "A" не получится. Либо меняйте порядок аргументов (что они значат я не понимаю, но это неважно), чтобы массив шёл последним. Либо передавайте массив по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
package matrix;

sub new {
    my ($class, $elements) = @_;
    return bless({elements => $elements}, $class);
}

sub min {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $min;
    foreach (@{$self->{elements}}) {
        foreach (@$_) {
            $min = $_ if !defined($min) || $_ < $min;
        }
    }
    return $min;
}

package main;

my $matrix = matrix->new(\@elems);
```